# Использование указателя this в шаблоне

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Добрый день.

Пишу простой код, хочу сделать контроль доступа к данным в классе через отдельный класс:

```
template<class Tclass, Tclass* classptr> class ptr_storage_access_control_tmp {
public:
};


class a {

    friend ptr_storage_access_control_tmp<a, this>;

public:

};
```

В строке

```
 friend ptr_storage_access_control_tmp<a, this>;
```

транслятор выдает диагностику:

> Ошибка (активно)  E0258   оператор "this" можно использовать только
>   внутри нестатической функции-члена

Вопрос:

1. Почему нельзя объявить другом такой класс?

Спасибо.

UPD1:

Да, забыл сказать, транслятор Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Причем здесь "нельзя объявить другом"? Компилятор же ясно вам сказал, что проблема в том, что за пределами функции-члена нет никакого this. "Друзья" в этой ошибке вообще никак не замешаны.

Comment: Так я и не использую this за пределами методов. Я как раз пытаюсь объявить друга. Простая декларация о намерениях, ничего более, никакого использования this. Просто указание на то, что здесь будет указатель на класс a.

Comment: Во-первых, у вас написано `this` - это уже *использование* `this`. Во-вторых, компилятор не умеет читать разумы и не знает, что вы пытваетесь сделать. С точки зрения языка С++ у вас написан какой-то бессмысленный код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что значение `this` известно только на этапе работы программы (а аргумент шаблона должен известен на этапе компиляции) и доступно только из нестатического метода. Если хотете дать доступ просто классу `ptr_storage_access_control_tmp`:

```
template<class Tclass, Tclass* classptr> friend class    
ptr_storage_access_control_tmp;
```

Comment: Это же только объявление, которое показывает, что доступ должен быть открыт. Никаких действий тут не происходит и никаких объектов не создается.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 В этом и проблема, значение `this` становится доступено только из методов класса после создания экземпляра объекта.

Comment: @pepsicoca1: "Это же только объявление, которое показывает, что доступ должен быть открыт." - это какие-то ваши собственные изобретения. В языке С++ нет такого "только объявления, которое показывает, что доступ должен быть открыт". С точки зрения языка у вас написана какая-то белиберда.

Comment: вообше нужно больше читать, изучать, перед тем, что что то писать ( лично мое мнение) ...

Comment: к тому же  у вас неопределен общий шаблон, а вы определяете специализацию с указателем...